Convert json to array and handle empty and null strings
Input: Null and empty strings are handled properly but the issue is with setting the value of tempName and name.
if tempName="" or null, the values of name need to be same. no change in value for name.
If tempName="SomeValue", the name field must be set to that "SomeValue"
Below is the input spec with tempName null and name as test1
`
[
  {
    "bI": {
      "id": "t1",
      "locale": [
        "id_ID",
        "id_ID"
      ],
      "tempName": "",
      "name": "Test1",
      "isActive": false,
      "pT": "Re"
    },
    "id": "t1",
    "ContextID": "id_ID",
    "cf": {
      "name": "asd"
    },
    "dE": {
      "sS": "arte"
    },
    "mk": {},
    "pd": {}
  }
]`

below is the Spec applies for handling null and empty values of tempName. this is handled as expected
`[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "[&1].&",
        "bI": {
          "*": "[&2].bI.&",
          "tempName": {
            "": "[&3].&2.&1",
            "*": {
              "@1": "[&4].&3.&2"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]`

Scenario 1: when above spec is applied to input json for tempName="" then the output of tempName is set to null as below.
`[ {
  "bI" : {
    "id" : "t1",
    "locale" : [ "id_ID", "id_ID" ],
    "tempName" : null,
    "name" : "Test1",
    "isActive" : false,
    "pT" : "Re"
  },
  "id" : "t1",
  "ContextID" : "id_ID",
  "cf" : {
    "name" : "asd"
  },
  "dE" : {
    "sS" : "arte"
  },
  "mk" : { },
  "pd" : { }
} ]`

Scenario 2: when above spec is applied to input json for tempName="abc" then the output of tempName is set to "abc" as below.
 
`[ {
  "bI" : {
    "id" : "t1",
    "locale" : [ "id_ID", "id_ID" ],
    "tempName" : "abc",
    "name" : "Test1",
    "isActive" : false,
    "pT" : "Re"
  },
  "id" : "t1",
  "ContextID" : "id_ID",
  "cf" : {
    "name" : "asd"
  },
  "dE" : {
    "sS" : "arte"
  },
  "mk" : { },
  "pd" : { }
} ]`

With the above spec null and empty string values of tempName is handled but when
Scenario 3 when tempName="" or tempName=null name, value needs to be as it is.
Scenario 4 when tempName="abc", value of name is set to be "abc" as tempName
However, Scenario 1 and 2 are handled with the below spec but Scenario 3 and 4 are not working.
Final spec for handling all the scenarios:
`[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "[&1].&",
        "bI": {
          "*": "[&2].bI.&",
          "tempName": {
            "": "[&3].&2.&1",
            "*": {
              "@1": "[&4].&3.&2"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "name": "=notNull(@(1,tempName))"
      }
    }
  },
{
    "operation": "remove",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "tempName": ""
      }
    }
  }
 
 
]`

Expected Output:
When tempName=""
`
[ {
  "bI" : {
    "id" : "t1",
    "locale" : [ "id_ID", "id_ID" ],
    "tempName" : null,
    "name" : "Test1",
    "isActive" : false,
    "pT" : "Re"
  },
  "id" : "t1",
  "ContextID" : "id_ID",
  "cf" : {
    "name" : "asd"
  },
  "dE" : {
    "sS" : "arte"
  },
  "mk" : { },
  "pd" : { }
} ]`

When tempName="abc"
 
`[ {
  "bI" : {
    "id" : "t1",
    "locale" : [ "id_ID", "id_ID" ],
    "tempName" : "abc",
    "name" : "abc",
    "isActive" : false,
    "pT" : "Re"
  },
  "id" : "t1",
  "ContextID" : "id_ID",
  "cf" : {
    "name" : "asd"
  },
  "dE" : {
    "sS" : "arte"
  },
  "mk" : { },
  "pd" : { }
} ]`


All the scenarios are handled by the below code and giving the expected output.
[ {
"bI" : {
"id" : "t1",
"locale" : [ "id_ID", "id_ID" ],
"tempName" : null,
"name" : "Test1",
"isActive" : false,
"pT" : "Re"
},
"id" : "t1",
"ContextID" : "id_ID",
"cf" : {
"name" : "asd"
},
"dE" : {
"sS" : "arte"
},
"mk" : { },
"pd" : { }
} ]

I'm not sure if I've fully understood your problem, but I’ve tried running your specs with different scenarios (TempName = "", null, and "value") and noticed that sometimes it didn't yield the expected results.
For example, when tempName was filled, the value of name didn’t change; this is because the spec you wrote in the modify-overwrite-beta isn’t entirely correct—you didn’t specify the value's location properly. Another issue occurred when tempName was set to null; in this case, the value disappeared due to Jolt's logic. To solve this, you simply need to add an underscore ("_") at the beginning of the value you want to remain present (the "_somekey" checks if somekey is already present, if not, it creates it, otherwise it does nothing).
The final spec is nearly identical to the one you provided, with only a few adjustments:
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "[&1].&",
        "bI": {
          "*": "[&2].bI.&",
          "tempName": {
            "": "[&3].&2.&1",
            "*": {
              "@1": "[&4].&3.&2"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "bI": {
          "_tempName": null,
          "name": "=notNull(@(1,tempName))"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]


I removed the remove spec because I didn't understand its purpose in your problem.
Let me know if this was helpful or if I misinterpreted something.
